# How to make overlay click-through

Tags: click, overlay, swiftui, click-through

I would like to have a `List` with an overlay that does not interfere with the tap reception in SwiftUI.

I have attempted to use an `.overlay` as such;

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<30){
            Text("Item \($0)")
        }.overlay(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.purple, .clear]), startPoint: .bottom, endPoint: .center))
    }
}
```

However, this results in the list not being scrollable (or if using `NavigationLink`s, not clickable).

How can I have an overlay (or Z-Stack element for that matter) not receive any taps?

Comment: With `.allowsHitTesting(false)` works for tappable controls (like Button), but for `List` and `ScrollView` does not work.